# Does convexity at a point imply existence of one-sided derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $\phi:\mathbb (0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function, and let $c \in (0,\infty)$ be fixed.

Suppose that "$\phi$ is convex at $c$". i.e. for any $x_1,x_2>0, \alpha \in [0,1]$ satisfying $\alpha x_1 + (1- \alpha)x_2 =c$, we have
$$
\phi(c)=\phi\left(\alpha x_1 + (1- \alpha)x_2 \right) \leq \alpha \phi(x_1) + (1-\alpha)\phi(x_2) .
$$

Assume also that $\phi$ is strictly decreasing in a neighbourhood of $c$.

> Do the one-sided derivatives $\phi'_{-}(c),\phi'_{+}(c)$ necessarily exist?

**Edit:**

As pointed by Aryaman Maithani if $c$ is a global minimum of $\phi$, then clearly $\phi$ is convex at $c$, but there should be no reason to expect for existence of one-sided derivatives. (e.g. $\phi(x)=\sqrt{|x|}, c=0$).

**Edit 2:**

In the example described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3747376/104576), the left derivative does not exist. Can we create an example where the right derivative does not exist?

Comment: I think $\phi:\Bbb R\to[0, \infty)$ given by $\phi(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ will give you a counterexample by considering $c = 0$. To suit your requirement for $\phi:(0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$, I think you can get it by shifting the graph. Something like $x\mapsto \sqrt{|x-1|}$ and $c = 1$.

Comment: Thanks, you are right of course! Convexity at a point $c$ always holds when $c$ is a global minimum of the function. So I guess I am really interested in the case where $\phi$ is strictly decreasing around $c$. (I have edited the question to reflect this). Thank you again for this observation.

Comment: Maybe you could look at the Slater's inequality for convex function (1981).Maybe there is an interesting link see also the condition  of the theorem.good day and good luck !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\phi:(-1, \infty) \to [-1, \infty)$ as
$$\phi(x) = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{1 - (1+x)^2} & x \le 0\\ 
-x & 0 \le x \le 1 \\
-1 & 1 \le x\end{cases}$$

A graph is shown below. (Courtesy of [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).)
[image: The graph]

Clearly, $\phi$ is continuous and strictly decreasing in $(-1, 1)$. Thus, choosing $c = 0$ satisfies the conditions. (It has to be shown that $\phi$ is convex at this point but that is simple.)
However, the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^-}\phi'(x)$ does not exist (as a real number).

---

To meet the conditions of your domain and codomain, consider $\tilde \phi := [x \mapsto \phi(x-1)+1].$

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a very nice counter-example. I guess you defined the last part to be constant $-1$ (and not continued with $-x$)  in order to make sure $\phi$ is non-negative, as I required? Also, I wonder how did you think about this example? Did you have any geometric/visual insight that you can describe?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. (In fact, I only realised the non-negative constraint when I started typing the answer.) As for the second part, I was trying to stick to a counterexample like the first time where the limit exists as $\pm\infty$ and not something more pathologically weird. So I just fiddled with a semicircle on one side and something else on the other side such that the line segment joining points from one side to the other would always be above $0$. I also had in mind that the function would have to have an abrupt change and it can't be convex on the interval.

Comment: That being said, I am interested in seeing a function where the one sided limits truly do not exist. (That is, not even in the extended real line.)

Answer (score 0):

This answer is merely an attempt to fill in the details in the example described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3747376/104576). Convexity of $\phi$ at $0$ means that

$$
0=\phi(0) \leq \alpha \phi(x) + (1-\alpha)\phi(y), \tag{1}
$$
for every $-1< x \le 0 \le  y \le 1$ satisfying
$$
\alpha x + (1- \alpha)y =0. \tag{2}
$$
In particular, for every $-1<x \le 0 \le y \le 1$, we should have
$$
0 \le \alpha \sqrt{1 - (1+x)^2}  + (1-\alpha)(-y)=\alpha\big( \sqrt{1 - (1+x)^2} +x\big).
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
x^2+x=x(x+1) \le 0,
$$
which holds since $-1<x\le 0$.

Now, suppose that $-1< x \le 0 \le  1 \le y $. The inequality $(1)$ holds if and only if
$$
0\leq \alpha \sqrt{1 - (1+x)^2} + (\alpha-1).
$$

we also have $0 \ge -\alpha x=(1-\alpha)y\ge (1-\alpha) \Rightarrow (\alpha-1) \ge \alpha x$, so
$$
\alpha \sqrt{1 - (1+x)^2} + (\alpha-1) \ge \alpha \big(\sqrt{1 - (1+x)^2} + x\big) \ge 0
$$
holds as before for $-1< x \le 0$.