# $0 \leq u - \ln(1+u) \leq u^2$ for $\mid u\mid < \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

I want to prove without calculator that :

$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:0 \leq u - \ln(1+u) \leq u^2\:\:$ for $\:\:|u|< \frac{1}{2}$

---

My attempt :

$$ \psi(u)= u - \ln(1+u)$$
$$\psi'(u)= 1 - \frac{1}{1+u} = \frac{u}{1+u} $$

so $\psi$ decreasing for $u <0$ and increasing for $u >0$ and $\psi(0) =0$
so $\psi \geq 0$

For the second inequality:

$$ \phi(u)=u^2- u - \ln(1+u)$$
$$ \phi'(u)= 2u -1 + \frac{1}{1+u} = \frac{u(1+2u)}{1+u}$$

So $\phi$ is decreasing for $u<0$ and increasing for $u>0$, and $\phi(0)=0$ so $\phi \geq 0$

Comment: For the first inequality, how do you get that $\varphi$ is decreasing? What about $u=1/4$?

Comment: I made a change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that

$$\psi(u)= u - \ln(1+u) \implies \psi'(u)= 1 - \frac{1}{1+u}  \implies \psi''(u)=\frac1{(1+u)^2}\ge 0$$

and since $\psi(0)=\psi'(0)=0$ we have $u - \ln(1+u) \ge 0$.

And since

$$f(u)=u^2-u+ \ln(1+u) \implies f'(u)=2u-1+\frac{1}{1+u}\implies f''(u)=2-\frac1{(1+u)^2}\ge 0$$

and since $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ we have $u^2-u+ \ln(1+u)\ge 0$.

Comment: Here $ -\frac{1}{2} < u < \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: We need to check $u= -\frac{1}{2} $, not $0$ , isn't it ?

Comment: @zestiria We can use convexity and notably [that result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1761801/505767).

Comment: Ok, cool. I made a new proof. Is it ok now ?

Comment: @zestiria The fact that $f''(-1/2)=0$ doesn't affect the result. It suffices to show that $u=0$ are point of minimum for both functions.

Comment: @zestiria Yes that's fine you have shown that $u=0$ is a minimum point.

Answer (score 1):

For the error in proof of first inequality pointed out in comments section :

you can prove it by checking that $\psi(u)$ is decreasing for $u < 0$ ,  $\psi(0) = 0$ and $\psi(u)$ is increasing for $u >  0 $

Comment: Thanks, I changed my proof for the first inequality.