# Is there a theorem for this true inequality about convex functions?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let y = f(x)  be the equation of a line (T), and y=g(x) the equation of a curve (C).
If g is convex on [a,b], and (T) is tangent to (C) on some point on [a,b], then f(x) $\leq$ g(x) on [a,b].
An analogous inequality can be found for concave functions.
It seems efficient to use it to prove some inequalities.
But can you formally use it, as you can for Jensen's inequality ?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1761801/42969 or this:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/668679/42969.

Comment: Also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function: *“A differentiable function of one variable is convex on an interval if and only if its graph lies above all of its tangents”*

Comment: @MartinR Thank you